# Smarty Variable for tax deductible

Tags: receipts, smarty

I'd like to add custom code in my contribution receipts that does the following:

{if $contributionIsTaxDeductible == True}
No goods or services were exchange for this donation 
Tax id 12-3456789
{/if}

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the API explorer? (Support -> Developer)

Comment: Yes I am familiar with it

Comment: how are you defining contributionIsTaxDeductible? Or is that the problem?

Comment: The financial type has a is_deductible setting

Comment: What about using a chained api call like this?

{php}
  $this->assign("param_api_financialtype_getsingle", ['id' => "\$value.financial_type_id", 'return' => "is_deductible"]);
{/php}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Contribution' action='get' return="financial_type_id" id=3783 api.FinancialType.getsingle=$param_api_financialtype_getsingle}